# SSRS - Multi Value Parameter Report Problem

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I have a quite strange / unusual request for an SSRS report.  The client wants to be able to paste in large lists of ID numbers from an Excel sheet column (normally < 100 values but can be as many as 20,000 + values) as a search parameter in the report.

Now, I know how to pass multi value parameters from SSRS to a stored proc etc, that's not the issue.  The issue is with this requirement to literally paste in a list of IDs into the multi value parameter input box and then limit the dataset based on that list (rather than pre-populate the Multi Value parameter with a list of values based on a query / SP as you normally would)

My question is what would be the best method / approach to this problem as I have never had a similar ask in many years of SSIS development?  I need to make the solution as "self-service" as possible too, so as easy as running an SSRS report from report manager ideally.  I know I could just import the Excel data into a table in the database and join to that etc but ideally would like something the user can run without the need for any tech input to import data or run SQL through SSMS to get the datset.

Comment: Assuming you can provide your customer access to the DB, let hi, upload his data from Excel to temporary table (simple VBA can do that) and take it from there. This way you can control data accuracy as well

Comment: Thanks Igor, but VBA / Excel with DB connections is DEF not an option.  I used to be one of those "VBA Developers"  back in the day creating solutions like that but no way that's gonna fly in our Prod environment!

Answer (score 0):

When you copy/paste from excel its just a tab delimited string. You can configure a string parameter to allow multiple values, and then in the expression editor, split the string by tab values or by line breaks.

Here's how:

- In the parameter properties check the 'Allow multiple values' checkbox on the
  general tab
- Then in the datasource properties click the 'fx' (expression) button next to the parameter on the parameters tab
- In the expression editor that appears, type the following:

```
=replace(split(Parameters!MyParameter.Value,vbCrLf),"\x0009","")
```

This will split the string by line breaks, then strip the tab characters out. After that you can treat it like any multi-valued parameter.

Comment: Thanks, but I did say "I know how to pass multi value parameters to a stored proc" - But, it is a nice clear / straight forward description for how to pass multi value parameters though to a Sproc though!!  (Although if you're using earlier versions of SQL (2008 back I think) then you'd also need to create a UDF string splitter function and then call that instead as the SPLIT function not valid in 2008 and earlier)

Answer (score 0):

If you have a typical multi-value parameter setup then you can just copy/paste the column from excel directly in, it will automatically put each cell row copied from excel on a new line.

So if your query looked something like

```
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE EmployeeName IN(@empName)
```

and empName was you report parameter, if no available values are configured you'll get an empty list when you click in the parameter field, just copy paste direct from Excel and it will work.

I'm not sure if there would be any limits or how good performance would be especially if copying thousand of values but certainly for a reasonably small number of items this will work.

The only other way I can think of that means no real extra work for the user would be to have them drop the workbook into a specified folder (maybe with a subfolder based on their SSRS username, then use openrowset to read the contents either directly into a dataset or better still, into a permanent table with their username and the parameter value on each row.

The openrowset statement could sit at the top of your main dataset query

Then your query could do something simple like

```
DELETE FROM myParamValueTable WHERE UserName = @UserID
INSERT INTO myParamValueTable
SELECT * FROM (OPENROWSET .....) xl

SELECT * FROM myTable t 
    JOIN myParamValueTable p 
    ON t.EmployeeName = p.EmployeeName
    WHERE p.UserName = @UserID
```

Comment: HI, thanks for your reply.  I had been using the paste directly into the parameter method, which works fine up to say 1000 ish values.  But the client can be pasting in 280000+ values so I can't use the actual parameter input box values like that.   Think it is going to have to be a drop the file in a location then read by openrowset into table then join from there.  Thanks, I just wondered if there was a more elegant way of achieving this in SSRS / Report manager but it doesn't seem so!

Comment: Yep, not ideal but limited options, unless you went for a purely Excel/PowerBI solution